# How to configure firebase-admin sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, webpack, firebase-authentication

~Hello, I'm developing a user control system with google firebase. 
Only 2 functions for the moment: add users and remove them.

For add a user is so easy, I only need to copy and paste the autogenerated script from the console, but the problem here is delete a user because I need admin-level auth for this, so, I've reading about node.js and I have a VPS running on Centos7, so I proceeded whith the instalation:

```
yum install npm
```

Then in the folder of my domain I used the following:

```
npm init
```

For generate the initial **package.json**:

```
npm install firebase-admin --save
```

And then I had no idea how to use it, since I understand that the function **require** is not defined for browsers since it is backend, I mean for the following error in the browser:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Reading a bit more I found that I can use something called webpack (the first time I use it) and I followed the next instructions:

```
  npm install --save-dev ts-loader webpack-node-externals
  npm install --global webpack
```

Then, my configuration files:

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js', 
        libraryTarget: 'this' 
    },
    target: 'node', 
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ]
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()] 
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**index.ts**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceWorker = require('./<MY_PRIVATE_KEY>.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceWorker),
    databaseURL: "https://<MY_DATABASE>.firebaseio.com/"
});
```

and after running the **webpack** command, is generated the **index.js** file that should be included in my website... but the problem is... I still have a error... (complete error in the attached image)

[Error of my website in the generated index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZtq1.jpg)

So...

I would appreciate if you help me solve the error... I'm a new in node.js
I only want to run the delete user function:

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
    .then(function() {
        alert("Successfully deleted user");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        alert("Error deleting user:" + error);
    });
```

Comment: You can't use firebase-admin with frontend code.  It's for backend code only.

Comment: So you just have to use cloud function and the delete function will be executed from firebase server side (with admin right).